# Google on Area 51, a proposed Q&A site for people interested in learning how to use Google products

Tags: discussion

Few minutes ago I found on Area 51 [Google](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101667/google?referrer=bdLbTX-vJYnLYejQCZKwpg2), a proposed Q&A site for people interested in learning how to use Google products.

I think that its scope is included in the scope of this site so I posted [a question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25654/133145) about this there.

I think that the proposal is on a very early stage and that some of you could be interested on it.

Answer (score 4):

Ugh. That's either too much overlap with Web Apps or, with the inclusion of Android, too broad.

I don't have high hopes for that one succeeding.

Comment: Few minutes ago I added some proposal questions related to "Google hardware". There was already a proposal question about Google Fiber and I'm thinking that also some about Google Express should be added, at least to discuss if they will be considered too localized or not.

Answer (score 0):

Finding things on the Internet is becoming increasingly important, so a site about Google Search usage would be useful I think.

But it does not seem to be the direction that proposal is going to, unfortunately.

4 out of its 7 non-negative questions overlap with existing sites, so I believe a reduction of scope is in order.

Comment: Maybe, but as Google is only one of dozens of search engines, a site just for Google Search would be of very restricted use.

Comment: At this time the proposal doesn't have enough followers/questions so it's very early to know to judge the direction of that the proposal is going to, I think.